# Git auto-complete

Tags: bash, command-line, autocomplete, git, command

I am using Git as many of you do. Also, I don't use any GUI for that — just CLI. So I was wondering: are there any way to make Git commands (`git status`, `git checkout` etc.) complete themselves when hitting Tab? Like other CLI commands do.

P.S. I'm using Arch Linux, if that anyhow matters.

Comment: What shell are you using? Bash?

Comment: Yes, Bash. Sorry for not mentioning that.

Comment: You have this file `/etc/bash_completion.d/git` or not, it belongs to core/git

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Add `source /usr/share/git/completion/git-completion.bash` to your `~/.bashrc`.

#### References

1. [Arch Linux Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Git)

Answer (score 0):

Run this on the Terminal:  `source /usr/share/git/completion/git-completion.zsh`

The below may be absolute for some users

`source /usr/share/git/completion/git-completion.bash`